# Perfmon no alerts

Tags: perfmon

I'm trying to setup a simple monitor that triggers when disk space reaches a minimum threshold.

To do this I have:

- created a new user defined data collector set
- selected 'Manual' for creation type
- selected 'Performance Counter Alert' as the type of data
- added % Free space for the C: instance as a counter
- set alert when below 90 as the counter to monitor
- set to run as administrator

In the data collector properties I then set it to log an entry in application event log and I also have a Powershell script that sends an email. However, nothing ever gets logged even though I know the % usage is far below the 90% threshold.

I have tried with setting MB Free space also and no event is ever logged.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, my hosting provider's support have taken a look and not been able to offer a solution (other than setting up a hacky asp script they will poll to do the same job :S) but I'd really like to get this working. I've tried to do the same on my local win7 machine with no success either.

Comment: are you sure that powershell emailing works? what command do you use for that?

Comment: This was some time ago but I vaguely recall using a script which leveraged an SMTP server.

Comment: ok, sorry didnt check the data. Do you still need help on that?

Comment: oh sorry I thought you were asking because you were trying to get emailing working yourself :P No I'm good thanks :)